# kubes : how to make the liveness/readiness retry before forcing the restart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Hy
I use kubernetes on a nodeJs project
the garbage collector take occasionnaly too much time,(we are trying to fix that)
But in the meantime we have another issue : if the liveness/readiness  is probed during the garbage collecting, then my project don't respond and the container is restarted.

Is there a way to make the liveness/readiness try multiple time before restarting the container?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `failureThreshold` parameter to configure how often a probe is retried before it is actually considered as a failure. Note that it will take `periodSeconds` before the retry is executed, so that can lead to longer delays until your app is restarted. Ideally in your case you could try to make the periodSeconds slightly longer then the longest expected gc pause.

See the Kubernetes documentation for more details on [probe configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes).

Comment: This is the correct answer. In addition to that, I'd recommend to double check the necessity of a liveness probe. While a readiness probe is a "best practice" to avoid routing traffic to a container that is not ready to receive traffic, the added value of a liveness probe should be evaluated case by case. Is there a known/observed status in the containers lifecycle where it really should be restarted? Not saying Liveness-Probes shouldn't be used, just saying they should be used with a little more caution.